Calculate Percentile_cont
How can I calculate Percentile_cont for 2 consecutive months in snowflake ?
Issue is not able to get it done for 2 consecutive month
Example-
Date           value
31-01-2023  0.74
28-02-2023  0.75
31-03-2023  0.77
30-04-2023  0.98
So now for 01 only 0.74 and null should be considered
For 02 , 0.75 and 0.74 shoupd be considered.

Can you provide more data, and the expected result, so that we can help here? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
